# Using scratch geodatabase if output parameter is required

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, scratch-workspace

For example, if I want to use the "Times" function in ArcPy, I would write something like this:

```
 New_Raster = arcpy.ddd.Times(Old_Raster,10,Workspace + "\\newraster")
```

but since the output parameter is required, I have to put in a file location and name for the third parameter.

How would I write the "newraster" to a scratch geodatabase?

Answer (score 1):

Without testing, but reading the [Scratch Workspace (Environment setting)](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/environment-settings/scratch-workspace.htm) help page. I think you would do this:

```
arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace = <path_to_your_scratch_geodatabase>
arcpy.ddd.Times(Old_Raster,10,"newraster")
```

Answer (score -1):

For the third parameter, enter the scratch workspace like so:

```
New_Raster = arcpy.ddd.Times(Old_Raster , 10, "user\\foo\\scratch_geodatabase\\new_raster")
```